# AJAX dynamically setting a select option before it has been inserted into page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am AJAX'ing in some data from a table and I want to dynamically set a drop down select box. I want to emphasise that this:

```
$("#measurement").val(data.something[i].measurement);
```

Will not work here because I'm creating the HTML in the AJAX callback and inserting onto the page after declaring everything I need from the data. I loop through the results and add all the HTML tags and dynamic info into a variable to which I then insert with `innerHTML = insertmsg;` The only way I can think of doing this is quite messy so if anyone has any better ideas it would be most appreciated! I'm thinking either another callback function afterwards which isn't very efficient OR something like this:

```
if(data.something[i].measurement == "option1text"){
      insertmsg += "<option selected='selected'>option1text</option>";
}
else if(data.something[i].measurement == "option2text"){
      insertmsg += "<option selected='selected'>option1text</option>";
}
```

and so on until I have an if statement for each option text. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could we have a little more context about your code?

Comment: I've added a bit more info but it is very straightforward. I loop through the AJAX response and declare all HTML into a variable to which I then insert into a div at the end of the callback function. if you have a specific question that would be easier to answer.